# Why is it that if $f(S)\subset f(T)$ then it is not necessary $S\subset T$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ and $S,T\subset X$, then

if $f(S)\subset f(T)$ then it is not necessary $S\subset T$?

Also

Why is it that $f(S-T)$ is not necessary a subset of $f(S) - f(T)$?

Are there any examples that proof these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any constant function. Let $S$ and $T$ be any two subsets so that $T$ does not contain $S$.

For strict inequality:

$f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R$ defined by $f(x)=|x|$.

Let $S=\{-1\}$ and $T=\{1,2\}$ ,we have $f(S)\subset f(T)$ and clearly $S\not\subset T$

For the final example we use the same function.

Let $S=\{-1,1\}$ and $T=\{1\}$. Then clearly $f(S-T)=\{1\}$ while $F(S)-f(T)=\emptyset$

Comment: What about the other part of my question?

Comment: I think there is a mistake in the other part of the question.

Comment: Why is it that $f(S-T)$ is not necessary a subset of $f(S) - f(T)$?

Comment: oh ok, Ill add a counterexample.

Comment: Basically it is because the function may not be injective.

Comment: If the function is injective then all of the claims you made are true.

Comment: Thank you this is really helpful just one more question why is that if $f^{-1}(S)\subset f^{-1}(T)$ then its not necessary that $S\subset T$?

Comment: because there can be various points which map to a specific point $p$. So if $f(u)=p$ and $f(v)=p$ we have $f\{u\}\subset f\{v\}$ and $\{u\}\not\subset \{v\}$

Comment: Is there a function that does that and on what subsets? thanks.

Comment: Any none injective function does that. Each of your claims is equivalent to $f$ being injective.

Comment: So if we choose $f(x)=|x|$ what choices should we make for $A$ and $B$ such that $f^{-1}(A)\subset f^{-1}(B)$ but $A\not\subset B$

Comment: I already answered that in the main body. $A=\{-1\}$ and  $B=\{1,2\}$.

Comment: Ok I get it now.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $f \colon \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ defined by $z \mapsto 0$ for all $z$. Set $S=\mathbb{Z}$ and $T=\{0\}$. Then $f(S) \subseteq f(T)$ but $S \nsubseteq T$.